# Does Fosc refer to the crystal frequency before or after PLL is applied for PIC18 microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, oscillator

If I have a PIC18 microcontroller with an 8MHz crystal and 4xPLL, is Fosc 8MHz or 32MHz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F<sub>osc</sub> is the clock eventually with PLL, so with an 8MHz crystal and 4xPLL you would have an F<sub>osc</sub> of 32MHz. However, note that this is divided by 4 internally, so that you will be able to handle 8 million instructions per second (MIPS).

I found this in the [18F2520/2620/4525/4620 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39626b.pdf), table 17-3 on page 187. You can see that F<sub>cy</sub>, the cycle frequency, equals F<sub>osc</sub>/4. F<sub>osc</sub> therefore has to be *with* PLL.